# Additional Row inserted using xlDown in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have the following macro defined which inserts rows into a sheet. After the rows are inserted at specified start addresses, the various ranges are then converted into Tables. My initial thoughts are that the issue lies with the use of `xlDown` - since this is the place in code where rows are inserted.

At present I have 7 such ranges, however the issue is that first three always have an additional row inserted - this was previously working with no issues, so the fact that its misbehaving is a puzzle to me.

The remaining ranges are correct. The `tableStartAdress` refers to named ranges whose values correspond to the first cell below the green title, ie A4, A12 etc. `rowsToInsert` for this example is always 38.

```
Sub InsertTableRows(tableStartAdress As String, rowsToInsert As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rowToCopy As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Range(tableStartAdress).Offset(1, 0).Rows.Copy

    rowToCopy = Range(tableStartAdress).Offset(1, 0).row & ":" & _           
                   Range(tableStartAdress).Offset(1, 0).row

    Rows(rowToCopy).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Range(tableStartAdress).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Resize(rowsToInsert, 1).Select

    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

The following pictures depict what I mean.

**Before:**

[image: How the wkSheet looks before date population].

Once data is populated the first three range/tables have an extra row

[image: Extra Rows], [image: Extra Row],

**Whilst the remainder are correct**

[image: Correct blank stuff]

Comment: @Ahmad: When you select the row to copy, does it have an empty row after it?

Comment: @ardman - the row that gets copied is actually the blank row you see in the before picture. So to answer the question no, since the following row is actually a placeholder for the subtotals that will be generated once populated with data

Comment: @Ahmad:  The problem might actually lie in your sub-totaling code rather than the code you have pasted above.

Comment: @ardman - nope, I dont think so -I have tested this. The extra rows are generated before the ranges are converted to Tables-so before subtotals are added

Comment: @Ardman - why did you ask about there being an empty row in the first comment?

Comment: @Ahmad:  It was to do with your selection.  Making sure that you only had the 1 row selected and not 2.

Comment: @Ardman - did have only one row selected. What seems to work is to have some data in the row below the subtotals row in the before picture. This makes no sense to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest simplifying your code to start. (Might help you track down were things are going wrong.) Since you don't need to select a range before you do something with it....

```
rowToCopy = Range(tableStartAdress).Offset(1, 0).Row & _
    ":" & Range(tableStartAdress).Offset(1, 0).Row
Rows(rowToCopy).Select
Selection.Copy

Range(tableStartAdress).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Resize(rowsToInsert, 1).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

is the same as...

```
Range(tableStartAdress).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Copy
Range(tableStartAdress).Offset(1, 0).Resize(rowsToInsert, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

which is much easier to look at. A couple thoughts: First, are you sure that tableStartAddress is really always a single cell (and the correct cell)? Are you sure that rowsToInsert is always 38? Beyond that, your code as it's currently written is copying an entire row and inserting it into a range that's theoretically 38 rows by 1 column. I would recommend rewriting this so you first insert however many rows you want, then fill the 38 x 1 range with the data that belongs there.